# UWP DependencyProperty Binding and DataTemplate Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, dependency-properties

I have a `PlaylistControl` (it is a `UserControl`) with a variable `ShowAlbumText` declared in this way:

```
    public bool ShowAlbumText
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(ShowAlbumTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShowAlbumTextProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowAlbumTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowAlbumText", 
                        typeof(bool),
                        typeof(PlaylistControl),
                        new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

And `ShowAlbumText` is used in a `ListView.ItemTemplate` in the xaml of `PlaylistControl` this way:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Music">
            <local:PlaylistControlItem DataContext="{x:Bind}" ShowAlbumText="{Binding ShowAlbumText}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

However, this `Binding` reports an error

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ShowAlbumText' property not
>   found on 'SMPlayer.Models.Music'. BindingExpression:
>   Path='ShowAlbumText' DataItem='SMPlayer.Models.Music'; target element
>   is 'SMPlayer.Controls.PlaylistControlItem' (Name='null'); target
>   property is 'ShowAlbumText' (type 'Boolean')

So how I can bind the `ShowAlbumText` to the `PlaylistControlItem`? I **understand** that `ShowAlbumText` is **NOT** a property of `Music` (`Music` is my ViewModel). It is a `DependencyProperty` of my `UserControl`. A more general question, how can I bind both `DependencyProperty` from my `UserControl` and `ViewModel` from `ItemsSource` to a DataTemplate?

Source [XAML](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml).

Source [Csharp Code](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml.cs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ElementName to make a binding point to a property of an element in your XAML instead of a property of the data context. In your case, you would want that element to be the UserControl/PlaylistControl.

Give the UserControl element a Name:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WhateverYourNamespaceIs.PlaylistControl"
    ...
    x:Name="Foo">
```

Point your binding to the element with that name:

```
<local:PlaylistControlItem DataContext="{x:Bind}" ShowAlbumText="{Binding ElementName=Foo, Path=ShowAlbumText}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your page a name in which listview is present like this

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestUwpApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestUwpApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    Name="MainPageName">
```

And then Bind Property "ShowAlbumText" like this.

```
<ListView>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Music">
        <local:PlaylistControlItem DataContext="{x:Bind}" ShowAlbumText="{Binding ElementName=MainPageName,Path=DataContext.ShowAlbumText}">
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```